# Create H2 Db from BatFile after reading CVS File

Tags: h2

Everything works just trying to eliminate a step
I have 2 batfiles

1)Reads a csv and creates a table and saves as compressed file

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1;
CREATE TABLE Table2 (col1VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,col2VARCHAR(10) NULL)
    AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('Table1.csv');

SCRIPT TO 'MyDB.sql' COMPRESSION DEFLATE;

2)Takes compressed file from 1st batfile and creates DB file

java.exe -Xmx512m -classpath h2.jar" org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:file:C:\Temp\MyDB;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE -user sa -password sa -script MyDB.sql -options compression deflate

Is there a way to create the DB file without creating the compressed file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your initialization commands into small SQL script and execute this script with `RunScript`:

`init.sql`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    col1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(10))
    AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('Table1.csv');
```

`java … RunScript … -script init.sql`

---

You can also run some commands during connection initialization with `INIT` parameter:

```java
DriverManeger.getConnection(
    "jdbc:h2:your_database;your_parameters;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'init.sql'",
            user, password);
```

or even

```java
DriverManeger.getConnection(
    "jdbc:h2:your_database;your_parameters;INIT=CREATE TABLE Table1 AS …\; CREATE TABLE …'",
            user, password);
```

---

You can export an existing database with `BACKUP` command:

```sql
BACKUP TO 'filename.zip'
```

The generated archive simply contains ready-to-use database files.